# PHP facebook login can't get email from user

Tags: php, facebook, email

I'm using code to login via facebook and get the user info including the email.. it works for the most part but I can't get the email in my array...

HERE is my code:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Session should always be active

$app_id             = 'appID';  //localhost
$app_secret         = 'secret';
$required_scope     = 'public_profile, publish_actions, email'; //Permissions required
$redirect_url       = 'URL'; //FB redirects to this page with a code

require_once __DIR__ . "/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php"; //include autoload from SDK folder

//import required class to the current scope
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id , $app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
}



if ($session){      

    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());


    //save session var as array
    $_SESSION["fb_user_details"] = $user_profile->asArray(); 

    $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["id"] ) )? $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["id"] : "";
    $user_name = ( isset( $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["name"] ) )? $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["name"] : "";
    $user_email = ( isset( $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["email"] ) )? $_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["email"] : "";

if(isset($_SESSION["fb_user_details"]))
    {
        print 'Hi '.$_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["name"].' you are logged in! [ <a href="?log-out=1">log-out</a> ] ';
        print '<pre>';
        print_r($_SESSION["fb_user_details"]);
        print '</pre>';
    }



}else{ 

    echo "we dont have a session";

    //session var is still there
    if(isset($_SESSION["fb_user_details"]))
    {
        print 'Hi '.$_SESSION["fb_user_details"]["name"].' you are logged in! [ <a href="?log-out=1">log-out</a> ] ';
        print '<pre>';
        print_r($_SESSION["fb_user_details"]);
        print '</pre>';
    }
    else
    {
        //display login url 
        $login_url = $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => $required_scope ) );
        echo '<a href="'.$login_url.'">Login with Facebook</a>'; 
    }
}
```

and my result is this:

```
Array
(
[id] => 
[first_name] => 
[gender] =>
[last_name] => 
[link] => 
[locale] => 
[name] => 
[timezone] => 
[updated_time] => 
[verified] => 
)
```

NO email in my array ? Any ideas why ?

I also tried adding this

```
$user_profile->getProperty("email");
```

after this line

```
$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

and still noting...  My permission seems to be ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Documentation says (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user?locale=en_GB):

This person's primary email address listed on their profile. 
This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available.

So it's not returning the email you are logging through, but the one listed on your profile.